# embedded linux, tty not working during boot

Tags: linux, embedded, embedded-linux, boot, tty

I'm writing a software to test some peripherals on my device.
I have to check some tty devices, so I writed a C binary that writes and reads from a given tty. It works perfectly called from command line, but it doesn't work if called from an init.d script.
Any ideas?

Comment: when do you call it?

Comment: in an init.d script, it is one of the last script that automatically starts.

Comment: describe "it doesn't work if called from an init.d script."

Comment: when I call it from the init script, I receive the right number of bytes, but they are all blank.

Comment: solved by adding a method with a system() that call the binaries.

Answer (score 1):

Login prompt appears after start-up scripts are executed - that is why they are called start-up scripts.

I am not sure changing the order would be wise and safe. I would probably wait (sleep) for a while. Just don't forget to run your program in the background mode, otherwise it'll block boot process:

```
my_test_tty_program &
```

Comment: I've added a sleep(30). I think it's some stdin, stdout or similar matter. I'm checking the "&" and I'll let you know.

Comment: It's called in that way:     /usr/sbin/itcdev all > /dev/null & and in it there is a sleep. Really strange.

Comment: why do you redirect stdout to /dev/null? remove it.

Comment: removed, nothing changed (except that I see the printf now)

Comment: solved by adding a method with a system() that call the binaries.